# Macro and Pre/Post Increment in C

Tags: c, macros, post-increment, pre-increment

I have noticed this strange behavior of macro functions while using pre increment operator. I know it is not preferable to use pre increment operator with macros but still I would like to know the reason behind the execution of the following 2 codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SQR(x) {x*x }

int main()
{
    int a=4;
    int b=SQR(a++);
    int c=SQR(++a);
    printf("%d.....%d....%d\n",b,c,a*b*c); 
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is:

```
20.....64....10240
```

The first value b is 20, which is okay 4*5. But why the value of C is 64 i.e. 8*8 instead of 7*8?

And I just replaced the sequence of execution like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SQR(x) {x*x }

int main()
{
    int a=4;
    int c=SQR(++a);
    int b=SQR(a++);
    printf("%d.....%d....%d\n",b,c,a*b*c); 
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is:

```
42.....36....12096
```

Strange isn't it? The pre increment again had some issue. It gave 42 i.e. 6*7 instead of 5*6 and after that the post increment also gave wrong answer 36 i.e. 6*6 instead of 6*7.

It would be a great help if anyone can explain why the outputs are like this?

Comment: undefined behavior

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior as OP might be confused about what macros do (as assumed by Sourav Ghosh's answer).

Comment: hey @Danh actually this question was asked in one of my exams, hence I thought there should be someway to get the answer.

Comment: Another useful and relevant Q&A is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MACROs are textual replacement, so your code

```
 SQR(a++)
```

expands to something like

```
 a++ * a++
```

and, `int c=SQR(++a);` to `int c = ++a*++a;`

which invokes  [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). To elaborate the *why* part for this, please refer to this well-written answer.

Comment: Ain't there any way to get the answer atleast for the first function, coz that is what I got in one of my exams

Comment: @user7297996 nopes, UB is...UB. that's it.

Comment: Okay thank you for ur help

Comment: If this is a question on an exam, either your teacher is tricking you and the answer is "undefined behavior", or your teacher has no idea what they're doing and has no business teaching C. (An alternative answer that I would have accepted would be, "I have no idea, but if you ever wrote code like this, you deserve to have your butt kicked, so it doesn't really matter.")